# TypeError when posting json list to flask route

Tags: json, python-3.x

so i made a RESTful API with python and flask and here is the route that accepts POST:

```
# Add employee
@api_bp.route('/api/employees/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_employee():
  first_name = request.json['first_name']
  last_name = request.json['last_name']
  age = request.json['age']
  isMaried = request.json['isMaried']
  salary = request.json['salary']
  new_employee = Employees(first_name, last_name, age, isMaried, salary)
  if new_employee:
    db.session.add(new_employee)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'success!'
```

I tried posting a json dictionary and it worked fine but when i try to post a list of dictionaries i get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because list of JSONs is not JSON itself
You can access your data like `request.form` and then for each JSON do `json.loads(index)` to validate if it is JSON

Or (the way I would prefer) you can rewrite you schema to accept JSON like this:

```
{
    "foos" : [{
        "prop1":"value1",
        "prop2":"value2"
    }, {
        "prop1":"value3", 
        "prop2":"value4"
    }]
}
```